# Load XpsDocument from a .XPS file into existing FixedDocument

Tags: .net, xaml, xps, xpsdocument

I'm trying to load a XPS file from disk and print it as part of a `FixedDocument` or `FixedDocumentSequence` of in memory documents I've created. They need to be printed as one sequence because they're duplexed.

Here's my best attempt so far:

```
// create my memory FixedDocument (a packing slip)
DocumentReference mainDocRef = GetMainDoc();  // created in memory

// load XPS document from file (to print on the back)
XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument("flyer.xps", FileAccess.Read);
var docSequenceFromFile = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
var xpsDocRef = docSequenceFromFile.References.First();

// try to combine together
FixedDocumentSequence documentSequence = new FixedDocumentSequence();
documentSequence.References.Add(mainDocRef);
documentSequence.References.Add(xpsDocRef);     // THROWS EXCEPTION

// print
XpsDocumentWriter xps = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
xps.Write(documentSequence, ticket);
```

I always end up with the exception :

> **InvalidOperationException** : Additional information: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

I've tried several ways to do this, but keep ending up with errors like this

How can I load an `XpsDocument` and print it as a second page in a `FixedDocumentSequence` I've created in memory?

Comment: WAG, but call [RemoveLogicalChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.removelogicalchild(v=vs.100).aspx) on the reference's FixedDocumentSequence.  This is all WPF, btw.  In WPF, elements have at most one "logical parent", as in the object that owns the instance you twiddle with in code (the visual tree is created from the logical tree, and can be different).  To do what you want, you need to disconnect the child from the parent so that you can re-attach it to a different parent.  The method I linked to should do this, I think.

Comment: @Will this is a protected method

Comment: Not just protected but also internal

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: That's why I said it was a WAG (wild-ass-guess).  However, the principal is still the same.  You HAVE to disconnect the child from the parent.  Period.  Without a sample project I can't tell you with a certainty how to do that. You can use the LogicalTreeHelper to find the parent, then examine it for methods or properties you can use to disconnect the two.  It's different for different framework types.  For example, to disconnect a ContentControl, simply null out it's Content property.  And, hey, worse comes to worst, use reflection to sneak behind the curtains.

Answer (score 0):

Simon_Weaver,

As I dont exactly know what is being returned by the `GetMainDoc()` method I have excluded that and just commented out the `mainDocRef` refrences however this seems trivial as your issue is adding the loaded xps file to your `documentSequence` and the `mainDocRef` is somewhat irrelevant to the question (please correct me if I am wrong).

Now the problem as stated is that the `xpsDoc` is loaded to another element (document) and we must detach it as the exception states. However the ability to do so is protected by an `internal` method. This being said the easiest way is just enumerate through all the pages of the document and create a new page from the source of the page being enumerated to a new document.

The final code looks something like.. (code commented)

```
//DocumentReference mainDocRef = GetMainDoc();  // created in memory. commented as I dont have a reference to what this object contains.

//create our new document reference to add the pages to
DocumentReference newDocReference = new DocumentReference();

// load XPS document from file (to print on the back)
using (XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(@"flyer.xps", FileAccess.Read))
{
    var docSequenceFromFile = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    var xpsDocRef = docSequenceFromFile.References.First();

    //get the fixed document to enumerate
    FixedDocument xpsFixedDoc = xpsDocRef.GetDocument(false);

    //get the fixed document to add to
    FixedDocument newFixedDoc = new FixedDocument();

    //set the new document reference
    newDocReference.SetDocument(newFixedDoc);

    //enumerate each page of the fixed document
    foreach (PageContent page in xpsFixedDoc.Pages)
    {
        PageContent newPageContent = new PageContent();
        newPageContent.Source = page.Source;
        ((IUriContext)newPageContent).BaseUri = ((IUriContext)page).BaseUri;
        newPageContent.GetPageRoot(true);
        newFixedDoc.Pages.Add(newPageContent);
    }
}

// try to combine together.
FixedDocumentSequence documentSequence = new FixedDocumentSequence();

//documentSequence.References.Add(mainDocRef); <<-- commented out, re-add after tests

//add the new document reference
documentSequence.References.Add(newDocReference);     

// print
XpsDocumentWriter xps = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
xps.Write(documentSequence, ticket);

mainDocRef = null;
newDocReference = null;
```

Now one thing to note is `XpsDocument` and `PrintQueue` inherit from `IDisposable`. (Dont need to tell you what to do there).

Now there could still be problems with the `GetMainDoc()` but as the reference to this method is not posted I cant test any errors here. Let me know how it goes.

Cheers. Nico